# Importing csv file where one DateTime field contains null

Tags: csv, ssms, flat-file

I have a csv file with 500k+ entries that I want to import to a table in ssms. The problem I'm encountering is that one of the DateTime fields sometimes contains NULL. I can't seem to figure out how to tell it to set it to null. I am trying to use the Import Flat File Wizard

This is one of the lines from the csv

```
146807000   2018-06-13 00:00:00.0000000 2018-06-13 00:00:00.0000000 10000-01    sv  SEK 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL    121.600000000
```

My Settings:
[image: Import Flat File Settings]

The error:
[image: Import Flat File Error]

Comment: That isn't a `NULL`, it's the **string** `'NULL'`; `NULL` and `'NULL'` are completely different values. You'll either need to remove the strings with the value `'NULL'` or import the data into a staging table and then convert only the valid date and time values, and replace the `'NULL'` values with `NULL` (look at `TRY_CONVERT`) when you insert it into your production table.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use a staging table and then use TRY_CONVERT and it worked!